# Given a p.s.d. matrix $X$ and vectors $a, b$, what is the relationship between $||a-b||_2$ and $a^TXa-b^TXb$?

Tags: normed-spaces, vectors

Given $X \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$, $a,b \in \mathbb{R}^N$

What is the relationship between $||a-b||_2$ and $a^TXa-b^TXb$?